# Porque a variável não é acessada fora da função?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Eu sei que existe escopo em javascript mas neste caso é diferente a variável ela é global segue o exemplo.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="input1" type="text" value="">

<p id="paragrafo"></p>

<button type="button" id="button1">Click</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  var name1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  document.getElementById("paragrafo").innerHTML = name1;
}

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Notem, que o código até ai funciona perfeitamente quando clicar no botão o valor que estiver dentro do `input` é retornado para o parágrafo com `id="paragrafo"` mas quando a variável é colocada fora da função o botão não consegue pegar o valor dela só se estiver dentro da função. Eu sei que o problema é bem simples fiquei alguns mês sem usar javascript e acabei esquecendo mais quem poder ajudar fico muito agradecido.

Comment: variáveis dentro de funções não são globais, sua pergunta é sua resposta

Comment: Que variável? Se está com problema em um código diferente deste não seria o caso de postar o outro código e não esse que você não tem problema?

Comment: @Davi, mas se a a variável `name1` fosse declarada fora da função, ela seria global, e a você poderia acessa-la dentro da função, concorda? Acho que essa não é o problema do Fernando, a pergunta não está clara, mas acredito que ele esteja iniciando a variável fora da função, e então esperando que ela seja atualizada conforme o valor do input é alterado, como se fosse uma referência. Como isso não acontece, ele acha que não está conseguindo acessa-la. Mas isso é só um palpite.

Comment: sim, minha pergunta foi sobre a variável no código ela está como uma variável que vale apenas dentro do seu escopo então ela se torna local, mas quando a coloco fora ela se torna global esse é o problema na minha pergunta faz referencia sobre a variável global não a local amostrei o código para vocês verem que está funcionando perfeitamente mas ao colocar a variável fora da função o botão não acessa ela mesmo ela sendo global.

Comment: Porque meu problema estava relacionado com essas linguagem se você sabe java ou php com certeza resolveria o problema

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que quando você coloca a linha do `var nome1` fora da função, esse codigo é executado logo quando a pagina carrega e seu `input` está vazio, logo a `var nome1` fica vazia, então quando a função é executada o innerHTML do `paragrafo` fica vazio e não ocupa espaço.

Se você concatenar a `name1` com outro texto já aparece texto no paragrafo...

```
 document.getElementById("paragrafo").innerHTML = name1 + "Olá";
```

Ou se colocar um texto no value do input:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" value="Hey">
```

Comment: Valeu colega, Ótima resposta ajudou muito!